# Error in numeric(h) : vector size cannot be NA/NaN

Tags: r, tableau-api, predictive

I worked on Tableau and R, I want to forecast school number yearly. I created two calculated field :
 dataforcast calculated field

```
DATE(IF [School Year] == { MAX([School Year]) } 
THEN DATEADD('year', 1, [School Year]) ELSE [School Year] END)
```

School number forecast calculate field but it shows an error:

> Error in numeric(h) : vector size cannot be NA/NaN

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast); 
x <- .arg1; 
y <- .arg2;  
myts <- ts(.arg1,start=c(2008,1), frequency= 1); 
myforecast <- forecast(myts, h=.arg1[1]); 
monthsts<-length(.arg1);  
append(.arg1[(.arg2[1]+1):monthsts], myforecast$mean, after= monthsts )", 
       SUM([Number of students]) , ATTR([Dateforcast]))
```

Answer (score -1):

In the TabPy [Github documentation](https://github.com/tableau/TabPy/blob/master/docs/TableauConfiguration.md), you'll see that the following is necessary:

> "For a SCRIPT call to Python to be successful, it needs to return a result explicitly specified with the return keyword (highlighted in red)."

[image]

Without the return keyword, nothing is brought back to tableau. Hence the NA/NaN error.

Hope this helps!